Saving a Post and a Video into a relational model using Laravel eloquent
I have created a migration name savables as follows, the goal is to attach, and detach the post_id or video_id along with its model type.
Schema::create('savables', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('savable_id');
   $table->string('savable_type');
});

The User, Post and Video Models contains the following functions
/* Post and Video Models */
public function users_saved(): MorphToMany
{
   return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'savable');
}
/* User Model */
public function saved_posts(): MorphToMany
{
   return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'savable');
}

public function saved_videos(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'savable');
}

>$post->saved_posts()->attach(auth()->id());
=null


Yess! I have solve this using OneToMany(Polymorphic Relationship)
Read more about it
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations
Use Save instead of Comment and all the logics will be the same.
Edit

Create Save Model Along with its migrations saves

$php artisan make:model -m Save


Edit migration file

Schema::create('saves', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('savable_id');
  $table->string('savable_type');
  $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
  $table->timestamps();
});


In Post and Video Models Put this

public function saves(): MorphMany {
  return $this->morphMany(Save::class, 'savable')->chaperone();
}


In Save Model Put this

public function savable(): MorphTo {
  return $this->morphTo();
}


Now you can start saving the Post and Video(In your controller)

$post->saves()->create([ 'user_id' => auth()->id()]);
$video->saves()->create([ 'user_id' => auth()->id()]);


To access this by User side,

In User Model, 
public function saves() {
  return $this->hasMany(Save::class);
}
//Now you can tweak this anywhere
$user->saves->where('savable_type', 'post'); //User will get the saved Posts
$user->saves->where('savable_type', 'video'); //User will get the saved Videos


